# Carrying and reusing information (json string) from an AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

**I have created a simple android app with 3 TextViews and then run an AsyncTask Task via a different class the next step would be to carry the information over and make the task reusable**.

The Task will consume a String (**URL**) and the **context of the MainActivity**.

The Task will make a simple **REST Request (GET)** and **retrieve a json string.**

I have then created another class that which gets the json response and creates a .json file saves it to

..../0/**Notes/launch.json**

The folder "Notes is created by myself via `file.mkdirs()`.

In the MainActivity I created an InputStream to read the .json file saved by the AsyncTask but once I try to open it, it gives me a `FileNotFoundException`.

Here's the code of my MainActivity.class

```
package com.example.root.example;

import android.Manifest;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 200);
    String url = "https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches/upcoming"; //Copy the url and open it in your browser to see the json.

    AsyncCall asyncCall = new AsyncCall(getApplicationContext());
    asyncCall.myAsyncTask(url);

   try {
        InputStream inputStream = this.getAssets().open("launch.json");
        int size = inputStream.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        inputStream.read(buffer);
        inputStream.close();
        String jsonStringFromFile= new String(buffer,"UTF-8");
        JSONObject launchObject = new JSONObject(jsonStringFromFile);
        System.out.println(launchObject.get("flight_number"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

This is the AsyncCall.class (making and retrieving the json etc..)

```
package com.example.root.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class AsyncCall {

FileCreator fileCreator = new FileCreator();
private final Context myContext;

public AsyncCall(final Context context) {
    myContext = context;
}

public void myAsyncTask(final String url) {

    AsyncTask asyncTask = new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .build();
            Response response = null;
            try {
                response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
                fileCreator.generateFile(myContext, myContext.getString(R.string.fileName), response.body().string());

            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.getMessage();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
  }
}
```

what am I trying to archive? I'm trying to save information (json here) and make it reusable just as the Falcon 9.

The issue lies in carrying information over to a different class.
If there's an alternative solution (other than saving a .json file) to fix this issue  then please don't hesitate to post it.

This is just my first issue, the second issue appears once you open the [api link](https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches/upcoming) and see that there are a few more than just one JSON String (0,1,2,3,4... upcoming missions).

I have no clue in any way to tacle the first let alone the second problem and have started over a few times, a while ago multiple times.

Comment: If youre using okhttp, you dont need asynctask

Comment: I am using okhttp. How would it work without asnytask since it would give me a networkonmainThread Exception in theory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your Activity, you can get the JSON like so

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {  
        try {
            final String responseData = response.body().string();
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseData);

            String flightNumber = json.getString("flight_number");
            // TODO: Load number into a TextView
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Looking at your API response, though, you'll actually need `new JSONArray(responseData)`, and you would have to loop over that to get each individual object's flight number

Comment: Here's the issue. I need to make it reusable. So that I can apply the value for flight number of the next mission (if you visit the api page you can see that there are more than just 1 missions coming up. So I need to be able to fetch the json strings of those upcoming missions as well. But I will def. give your solution (without asynctask) a try.

Comment: If you want to refractor this, then the `new Callback() {}` can be defined anywhere. A separate class, a field, a local variable, etc. The point here is that `.enqueue()` performs the background network call rather than loading an AsyncTask. Regarding the values, you need to be using a `JSONArray`, the given answer here will actually fail to parse the response

Comment: This solved my problem. As written in the comment section you have to replace the jsonobject with an jsonarray. You will have to use jsonarray.getJSONObject.... to access the values.